# Are there $\delta_n<\alpha$ and $x_n\in X$ such that $\{\varphi_{(-\delta_n, \delta_n)}(x_n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a cover for $\varphi_\mathbb{R}(x)$.

Tags: dynamical-systems, group-actions

Let $\varphi:X\times \mathbb{R}\to X$ be a continuous action on compact metric space $X$. Fix $\alpha>0$ and $x\in X$.

Are there $\delta_n<\alpha$ and $x_n\in X$ such that $\{\varphi_{(-\delta_n, \delta_n)}(x_n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a cover for $\varphi_\mathbb{R}(x)$.

Please help me to know it.

Comment: You probably want a sequence $\{x_n\}$ that does not depend on $x$, right? Otherwise it is not difficult to cover the path of $x$ by a countable collection of intervals.

Comment: @uniquesolution, it is not important that $\{x_n\}$ is dependence or not. Only I need $\delta_n<\alpha$

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your notations properly, $X=[0,1], \phi (x,t)=t$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, $1$ for $t >1$, $0$ for $t <0$ and  $\alpha =1/2$ gives  counterexample.

Comment: But $\varphi:[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$

Comment: @user479859 I have modified the definition of $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks. If I understood your example, for this action we have $\varphi_\mathbb{R}(x)=[0, 1]$ while $\varphi_{(-\delta_n, \varphi_n)}(x)=[0, \delta_n)$. Since $\delta_n<\frac{1}{2}$, we can not find a cover for $\varphi_\mathbb{R}(x)$.

Comment: Do you extend your example for a compact metric space with dim(X)>2?

Comment: Define $\phi :[0,1]^{k} \times \mathbb R \to [0,1]^{k}$ by $\phi ((x_1,x_2,...,x_k),t)=(t,t,...,t)$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$, $(0,0,,,0)$ for $t <0$ and $1$ for $t >1$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, $\varphi:X\times \mathbb{R}\to X$ must be continuous action, hence $\varphi(x, 0)=x$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: @user479859 The function in my answer is a continuous function.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, In a paper, author gave a proof for it, but I did not understand it

Comment: If $\varphi_\mathbb{R}(x)$ is a closed( and hence Lindelof) subset of $X$ or the induced map $\varphi^x:\mathbb{R}\to \varphi_\mathbb{R}(x)$ defined by $\varphi^x(t)=\varphi(x, t)$ is a homeomorphism on to $\varphi_\mathbb{R}(x)$. In any case we can arrange sequence $x_k\in X$ and $\delta_k<\alpha$ such that $\{\varphi_{(-\delta_k, \delta_k)}(x_k): k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ covers $\varphi_\mathbb{R}(x)$.

Comment: The above statement is replyof my question in a paper, but I don not understand it. Please help me to know it